# C++ why doesn't sizeof include the address size of an object instance?

Tags: c++, object, instance, sizeof

I was just wondering. If you create an object instance A with no data, the size of the class A is 1. C++ requires that this is minimally 1 byte. This is not my question.

Question:

The instance of A would also have a 64-bit address (if a 64-bit processor). Why isn't this 64-bit address included in sizeof? Why isn't it 8 + 1 = 9?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

union B
{
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    std::cout << "Size of A: " << sizeof(a) << " Size of B: " << sizeof(b) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Object A address: " << &a << " Size of Object A address: " << sizeof(&a) << std::endl; 
}
```

Output:

```
Size of A: 1 Size of B: 1
Object A address: 0x759c4d77611f Size of Object A address: 8
```

From what I understand, if you create an instance of A, you create a 64-bit address and the data immediately follows that address in memory.

So it would look like:

[A instance - 8 bytes allocated][1 data byte]

**Edit:**

These guys are totally right. I am wrong. There is no 64-bit address to the object instance created. The data itself is in memory.

If you create a pointer to the object, then that creates a 8-byte memory allocation but the object instance itself does not create an 8-byte pointer. It only creates the data in memory.

Comment: The address of an object is not stored inside the object. You don't create an address, it **has** an address by virtue of where it is stored.

Comment: I'm genuinely interested to learn where you heard that this is how objects are laid out in memory. What benefit would there be in siting the address of an object right next to it? That's like if Google Maps only gave you directions to cities you were already in.

Comment: The address is computed, as the result of an expression. It's not already stored in one of the operands. That's like saying that "1" has to store the value "2" somewhere because that's the result of the expression "1 + 1".

Comment: As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185337/c-why-doesnt-sizeof-include-the-address-size-of-an-object-instance#comment85377001_49185384) from OP, the misunderstanding originated from different code. As such I have voted to close this question as somewhat equivalent to a typo and not useful to future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I understand, if you create an instance of A, you create a 64-bit address and the data immediately follows that address in memory.

No. If you create an instance of A, you create an instance of A. That's it.

That object's address then tells you where that object is. If you obtain that that address (with `&`, as shown) and save it into a pointer, then the pointer variable itself takes up some space, sure. But otherwise, no.

`sizeof` gives you the size of an object. Not the size of an object, plus the size of a pointer.

There is no need for the size of a pointer to be added automatically. That would actually be really annoying, because you'd have to keep subtracting it all the time to get `sizeof` to do something useful.

I can't think of a single use case for getting the combined size of an object, and the size of a pointer to that object, in a single number.

Comment: "I can't think of a single use case" - nor can I but, on the rare-to-non-existent cases where it *may* be needed, you could just use `sizeof(ptr)+sizeof(*ptr)`.

Comment: Or, because we don't have raw pointers hanging around, `sizeof(obj)+sizeof(&obj)` ;)

Comment: ok yah i totally agree that it would be annoying to have to subtract the class instance address every time. Very much agreed.

When you say "No. If you create an instance of A, you create an instance of A. That's it." that is not correct. it absolutely creates a 64-bit, in this case, address of the object instance. It doesn't just create the data within the object and then magically know where that data is.

Comment: @user2654735: Okay, you know best then.

Comment: Well crap! Alright so I had thought that an address to the object instance was created because I had put a union around an object that had a virtual function in my code. I didn't realize that the 8 bytes were added because of this and not the object instance.